# Cambiar datos del connectionString app.config en tiempo de ejecución

Tags: c#, app.config

Hola tengan buen día chicos. Tengo una situación que me está dando mucha lata. He revisado mucha información de ejemplos e incluso de hilos en este foro pero no he encontrado algo que logre resolverme. Tengo mi aplicación en Windows Form que desde un formulario de configuración estoy cambiando la base de datos a la que se conecta la aplicación pero para que aplique los cambios tengo que cerrar la aplicación y abrir para ver los cambios que hice en mi app.config pero lo que requiero es que al darle guardar los cambios, lo haga sin salir de la aplicación. Según varios ejemplos debe hacerlo con el código que anexo pero no he logrado que guarde sin salir y volver a entrar a la aplicación.

Este es mi método que hace los cambios:

```
public class SettingAppFile
{
    Configuration config;

    public SettingAppFile()
    {
        config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
    }        
    public string GetConnectionString(string name)
    {
        return config.ConnectionStrings.ConnectionStrings[name].ConnectionString;
    }

public void SaveConnectionString(string key, string value)
    {
        config.ConnectionStrings.ConnectionStrings[key].ConnectionString = value;
        config.Save();
        ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("connectionStrings");
        Properties.Settings.Default.Reload();
        //config.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified);
    }
```

Y este es mi código donde hago uso del método para cambiar:

```
string connectionString = string.Format("Data Source={0};Initial Catalog={1};Persist Security Info=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;User ID={2};Password={3};", Settings.Default.dataSorce.ToString(), aliasBd, Settings.Default.usuarioConexion.ToString(), Settings.Default.contraseñaConexion.ToString());
        SettingAppFile setting = new SettingAppFile();
        setting.SaveConnectionString("NombreConexion", connectionString);
        ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("connectionStrings");
```

Gracias por la ayuda

Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Te comparto el metodo que me ha funcionado a mi!
Primero, tienes que crear las llaves que quieres utilizar en el apartado Settings.settings

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ahi ingresa los nombres y tipos de datos. Te comparto un ejemplo. Notarás que existen tipo `Application` y `User`, la diferencia está en que los tipo `User` puedes cambiarlos en tiempo de ejecución, mientras que los otros son estáticos.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Siguiendo el ejemplo anterior. Si quisiera cambiar el username o password, sería de la siguiente manera:

```
Properties.Settings.Default.username = UserTxt.Text;
Properties.Settings.Default.password = PassTxt.Text;
Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
```

Para leer información de mi Settings es tan sencillo como esto:

```
UserTxt.Text = Properties.Settings.Default.username;
```

Espero pueda ser útil para resolver tu problema! Saludos.

Comment: Incluso manejo variables tipo User. He podido identificar lo siguiente: al ingresar por primera vez si me hace los cambios pero si sobre la misma ejecución cambio de nueva cuenta los datos de conexión, sólo me aplica los cambios si salgo y vuelvo a entrar, de lo contrario siempre me aplica los cambios del primer cambio y no de los subsecuentes. En el mismo Form tengo varios métodos ques e conectan a bases de datos, pero toman siempre la primera cadena y no los cambios posteriores al primer cambio, pero si leo los datos de conexión desde ese mismo form si me da los cambio.